# Can not access OKHttp package in android studio , but throws exception from Okhttp package?

Tags: android, ssl, android-studio, okhttp

I have a native android app for https connection demo, I got exception like this::

[image]

my connection code is simple:

```
URL url = new URL("https://192.168.1.5:7443/worklightconsole");
        HttpsURLConnection urlConnection =
                (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        HostnameVerifier sss=urlConnection.getHostnameVerifier();
       // urlConnection.setHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);
        InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
```

So I assumed that android-21 api used okhttp for default connection, however, if I typed **com.squareup.okhttp** in android studio it does not show up the auto-complete for classes in the okhttp package, which disable me to debug the hostname verifier **sss**, noted that i debug the programme I can see the sss is actually a "OKHostnameVerifier" type, I need to debug some of the methods in this class hence I really want to know how to debug Okhttp.
[image]
[image]

**In other classes I can press CMD+Click to enter that class and set break point**

Comment: `com.squareup.okhttp` is different from `com.android.okhttp` Newer versions of Android have OkHttp built in, but not the squareup one.

Comment: But even if I type com.android I can not find the okhttp package...do you have any idea how i can debug this package?Thanks~

Comment: I'm not sure. Can you debug other android internal Classes ? Is target SDK set to 4.4 or higher ?

Comment: Yes, i can debug other class , just press CMD+Click I can enter that java file and set breakpoint. im using api 21

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your Gradle file under compile:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0'
```

Comment: Im not able to add this dependency to project

Comment: Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0.
     Required by:
         MyApplication:app:unspecified
      > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/okhttp/okhttp/2.2.0/okhttp-2.2.0.pom'.
         > peer not authenticated

Comment: @Qing Were you able to resolve the issue you are facing? I am facing exact same issue. I am not able to add okhttp in gradle build.